# Createigenface opencv function

Tags: java, opencv

I'm working on a face recognition project but unfortunately I have no experience on working with OpenCV. I had a problem while calling createEigenface function and for this reason I created the following simple script:

```
/*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
package inc;

import org.opencv.contrib.FaceRecognizer;

/**
 *
 * @author ali
 */
public class Inc {

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO code application logic here
        FaceRecognizer faceRecognizer = createEigenFaceRecognizer();

    }
}
```

When building i received the following error:

> *error: cannot find symbol
>           FaceRecognizer faceRecognizer = createEigenFaceRecognizer();   symbol:   method createEigenFaceRecognizer()   location: class Inc 1
>   error*

Mentions:

- I use Netbeans program( I've also used eclipse but the same error)
- added opencv_library-2.4.3 version which include org.opencv.contrib.FaceRecognizer

Could you please explain why I get this error! Any idea would be helpful! Thank you!

Comment: did you build your OpenCV library with contrib modules??

Comment: Sorry for my late response. I didn't build OpenCV with contrib modules. I have tried to do this but no result because it shows me that the opencv is compiling for more than 2 hours. I rebuilded it and the same result. Could you please indicate some steps to follow?

Comment: follow the steps mentioned here https://github.com/opencv/opencv_contrib

Comment: One more question, i used cmake-gui and as compiler MinGW... and i don't know what the above phrases refer to " build the opencv core with the method you chose (make and make install if you chose Unix makfile at step 6)

to run, linker flags to contrib modules will need to be added to use them in your code/IDE. For example to use the aruco module, "-lopencv_aruco" flag will be added.

Comment: And how to import builded files into netbeans in order to use them in my project?